# Swift Expected argument type `_?`?

Tags: swift, generics, weak-references

Can anyone explain to me what this error means and what is wrong with this attempted implementation of a Weak wrapper in Swift.

Just copy this into a new Playground:

```
import Cocoa

public struct Weak<T> where T: AnyObject {
    weak var value: T?
    
    init (_ value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

public protocol MyProto: class {
}

public class Foo: MyProto {
}

var foos = [Weak<MyProto>]()
let foo = Foo()

for foo in foos {
    if let bar = foo.value {  // 'MyProto' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'
    }
}

foos.append(Weak(foo as MyProto))  // Cannot convert value of type 'MyProto' to expected argument type '_?'
```

I get the errors:

> error: 'MyProto' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'
>
> error: cannot convert value of type 'MyProto' to expected argument type '_?'

Comment: See the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/q/47440451/2976878

Comment: Does this mean I have to give up on generics and explicitly cast everything? Ugh.

Comment: Why are you using `AnyObject` instead of `Any`?

Comment: @devios1 Is marking the protocol `@objc` a potential solution for you? `@objc` protocols can conform to themselves. Otherwise you'll want a type eraser.

Comment: @creeperspeak weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Comment: All I'm trying to do is hold an array of weak references to protocols. Is there a saner way?

Comment: @Hamish Well I can try converting all my classes to `@objc`, if that will solve it. But I've already been down that path and don't really want to go back. :/

Comment: @devios1 The classes don't have to be explicitly `@objc` (and therefore don't have to inherit from `NSObject`) in order to conform to an `@objc` protocol.

Comment: @Hamish Unfortunately the methods I actually need in the protocol need to reference my main `Node` class and can't represent it in the protocol unless it is also `@objc`, creating a chain reaction of dependencies.

Comment: I'm researching Type Erasers now…

Comment: I couldn't figure out any way to do a type eraser for a weak reference so I ended up just forgetting about generics and implementing a concrete weak class for each place it is needed. Really really sad that I am forced to do this when generics could have been such a reusable solution.