# Swift 4: generic conforming to AnyObject does not accept a protocol conforming to AnyObject

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I need to create an array of type-safe weak references

1. a structure that holds a 'type-safe' weak reference and can be an element of an array:

   ```
   public struct WeakRef<T: AnyObject>: Hashable {
       public weak var ref: T?
       public let hashValue: Int

       init(_ ref: T) {
           self.ref = ref
           self.hashValue = ObjectIdentifier(ref).hashValue
       }
   }

   extension WeakRef: Equatable {
       public static func ==(lhs: WeakRef<T>, rhs: WeakRef<T>) -> Bool {
           return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
       }
   }

   extension WeakRef: Comparable {
       static public func < (lhs:WeakRef<T>, rhs:WeakRef<T>) -> Bool {
           return lhs.hashValue < rhs.hashValue
       }
       static public func <= (lhs:WeakRef<T>, rhs:WeakRef<T>) -> Bool {
           return lhs.hashValue <= rhs.hashValue
       }
       static public func >= (lhs:WeakRef<T>, rhs:WeakRef<T>) -> Bool {
           return lhs.hashValue >= rhs.hashValue
       }
       static public func > (lhs:WeakRef<T>, rhs:WeakRef<T>) -> Bool {
           return lhs.hashValue > rhs.hashValue
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have a protocol which needs to be used with this weak ref:

   ```
   protocol LemmingTrackingProtocol: AnyObject {
       func onLemmingZPositionChanged()
       func onLemmingDrop()
   }
   ```
3. this is possible:

   ```
   var trackers = [WeakRef<LemmingTrackingProtocol>]()
   ```
4. but this is not:

   ```
   func addTracker(_ tracker: LemmingTrackingProtocol) {
       let tracker = WeakRef(tracker) // <-- Cannot invoke initializer...

       ...
   }
   ```

Please kindly give me a hint of what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/47441073/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/47440451/2976878

Comment: thank you Hamish, I should have searched for the answer more attentively; adding @objc to the protocol did solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

just add `@objc` to required protocol (in my case `LemmingTrackingProtocol`)

**Warning**

though this works, [you'll probably get stuck with not being able to create an extension with your `@objc` protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487168/non-objc-method-does-not-satisfy-optional-requirement-of-objc-protocol)

**Detailed**

according to @Hamish links provided:

1. this is a (sort of) bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55, and it is still present in Swift 4
2. [protocols do not (should not) always conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878)